# Polling with timer and http.get strategy

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, timer, polling

I need to serve live market data to users of my website. I get the stock price by making requests to an external API. I'm using socket.io to serve the data to the users. 
Since market datas change every milliseconds, I need to refresh them at least every 5 or 10 seconds.

Let's say I get 3 users connected on my website :

- User 1 is viewing stock "GOOGLE".
- User 2 is viewing stock "APPLE".
- User 3 is viewing stock "APPLE".

At this time, my server will have to poll only 2 differents stock price and cache them.

Now I have two strategies in mind, both with pros/cons :

**Strategy 1**

- Each time a user connects to socket.io, it triggers a timer (ie : timer[User1]) that repeats every 5 seconds.
- The timer checks if the stock in question is already polled by another user. If so it sends via socket.io the cached data to the user. If not it calls the function "getStockPrice" (which makes the http call to the API).

Globally, this strategy is easy to develop, but I will face the problem of having thousands of timers running (if I get thousands simultaneous visitors).

**Strategy 2**

Using a global timer that get all the stocks to serve in a list/queue and serve them via socket.io broadcast :

- Each time a user connects to socket.io, it registers this user to the specific room and add the stock in the list if it's not already in.
- The global timer get the list (every 5 seconds) and for each item of the list it calls the function "getStockPrice" and broadcast the result to the correct room.

With this strategy I will not face the problem of multiple timers. The problem will be that every 5 seconds my server will start doing thousands http requests at the same time. (In strategy 1, the http calls will be in a random range between 0 - 5 seconds). 
I could maybe solve this problem by using something like a queue/dequeue but is that enough to clear the queue every 5 seconds ?

Theses are the two strategies I have in mind but maybe there are other ones or should I simply use one of these two with some changes. What do you think ?

Comment: I don't think the problem you have in the second one is that bad. Requests would be done asynchronously in the loop, so it should work a lot better than when using sequential requests or thousands of threads in other languages.

Comment: What about the strategy 1 ? Is the use of multiple timer bad ?

Comment: I don't know. But it seems to me more clean that only one thing fetches the stocks and updates the caches than each client dealing with that. Also note that nothing forces you to make all the calls on the same time in the second case (you can create a timer for each update in a random value between 0 and 5 seconds). The number of timers you have here should still be lower than one for each user.

Comment: Strategy 2 is going to be your better choice IMHO. Multiple timers per connection isn't going to scale as well.